# twitter bootstrap carusel - нужна помощь!

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, wordpress, javascript

Есть сайт , http://non-toxic.com.ua/ использую http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel неработает =), скажите где исправить или куда копать =)!

**Update:**
Проблема с контролом была в том что я не заменил в data-target значение с myCarousel на jumbotron, так как в самом начале он объявлен id="jumbotron".

Comment: onready для начала: правда controls всё равно не работают

    jQuery(function($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 3000
        });
    });

Comment: Благодарю, хоть что-то заработало =).